# Global Indexing in Graph Databases

Tags: database, graph-databases

I am very new to graph databases and am trying to work on a survey of different graph databases. I am not able to understand what exactly the global indexing in graph databases are.

Can someone please help me to understand what is Global indexing in Graph Databases.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether all graph databases agree on the notion of what a global index is, but generally it means an index that applies to the whole graph. Such an index allows to efficiently retrieve vertices based on some indexed property, e.g.: *find all `person` vertices with the name `Manoj`*. Most graph queries use a global index to find one or a small number of vertices as an entry point into the graph and then traverse the graph from there.

Opposed to global indexes are *vertex-centric indexes*. They only apply to a specific vertex and can be used to make queries with so-called *supernodes* more efficient. The idea here is to index a property of incident edges of the vertex that can reduce the number of neighboring vertices returned to those that are really interesting for the query. Such a vertex-centric index could for example for twitter be used to index the `followedSince` property on `follower` edges. This would allow to efficiently query for all followers of Katy Perry that began following her on her birthday. Without an index you would have to check the property for all of her (currently over 95 Mio.) followers for this query.

(Your question didn't mention vertex-centric indexes but I think it helps to understand why global indexes are called that way when you know about vertex-centric indexes, as they are basically local indexes.)

For more information about indexing in graph databases see the respective sections in the documentation of graph databases like [Titan](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html) or [DSE Graph](https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/graph/using/indexOverview.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It really helped me to get an idea.. Appreciate your help.